# how to divert incoming all tcp packets at eth0 to socks proxy and to eth1 of same host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, socks

I have a three ubuntu linux hosts.
host 1,host 2 and host 3.
I want to pass data from host 1 to host 3 via host 2.
But specifically I want to pass all incoming traffic of host 2 to socks proxy then to host 3.

```
host 1 eth0: 192.168.1.10
host 2 eth0: 192.168.1.50
host 3 eth0: 192.168.1.11
```

I enabled ip_forward in all hosts.
in host 1, I set

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.1.50 dev eth0
```

In host 2,

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.1.50 dev eth0
```

In host 3,

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.1.50 dev eth0
```

I run redsocks in host 2 to get the traffic from host 1 and divert again to host 3.
But data not reached redsocks.?.
What may be my problem.
Anyother idea on this.
Thanks,
Kumar Raj